# converting from raid 10 to raid 1 on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: ssd, raid1, raid10, supermicro

My current setup is that my OS and other important installed files are all installed in my raid 10 array, however, I need the 2 drives (ssd)  in the array for something else, is there a way to convert my existing raid 10 to raid 1? or do I need to clean install? Can I just backup my drive C, then reformat my raid to configure it to raid 1 then put my backup back? My OS is windows server 2012 r2. my raid controller is the Avago Megaraid 3108 and the server brand is supermicro. Any suggestions will be nice too, Thanks!

Comment: `my raid controller is the onboard intel one` - Seriously? That's all you've got to give us in the way of information? It's the onboard intel one? That certainly narrows it down for us and ensures that you'll get laser focused anwers.

Comment: Hi, sorry for that bad info, because that is what my superiors told me, on what it contains, I'll update if I get more info,

Comment: Hi, my raid controller is the Avago Megarid 3108

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible. But it depends on what drivers / OS components you use and which drives "you need". "the onboard intel one" RAID controller sounds like a fake hardware controller, with implementations in your OS. As we don't know the specific model number, I strongly advise against this (well, I generally advise against this). I firmly believe it's no great idea to try such shenanigans in a production environment, much less with a "fake" hardware RAID controller.

Stay safe and reinstall the OS, or do a **complete** backup of your server and just try it, but be sure to be able to roll back any changes of your RAID.

Comment: Hi Sorry for the wrong information, my raid controller is the Avago Megaraid 3108